# How to allow "append only" (push) access from a remote server to a central server?

Tags: linux, rsync, file-sharing, scp, file-transfer

How to allow a remote server to push data onto a central server without having any other access.

That is, how to allow the remote server to only append but not overwrite or read files on the central server?

The reason for this is that the remote server is a less secure IOT device which still needs to transfer it's data over the network.

What are the possible approaches and how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the central server can have a firewall setup that would the first approach. You can open up a specific port and allow the remote server to only do the append only operation.